# The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect system call from qt creator c++

Tags: c++, qt, batch-file, command-line

When I run the command `C:\My Programs\CPU Analysis\scripts\ruinIODump.bat` from the command line, the command runs fine, but when I run the command from qt creator as:

```
system("\"\"C:\\My Programs\\CPU Analysis\\generateSanity_Scripts\\runIODump.bat\"\" \"\"C:/My\ Programs/CPU\ Analysis/iodump/065901_iodump.txt\"\"")
```

I get the error: `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

...

I've tried running the commands in the .bat file directly through the system() command and I've tried changing the quotation marks and I've tried using escape characters, but I keep getting the same error.  How can I get the .bat file to run from qt creator? I looked at the other SO questions similar to this, but none of them answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the Separators, as MCDC said.

I recommend use `QProcess` with `QDir::toNativeSeparators`, example:

```
const QString app = QDir::toNativeSeparators("C:/My Programs/CPU Analysis/generateSanity_Scripts/runIODump.bat");

const QString params = QDir::toNativeSeparators("C:/My Programs/CPU Analysis/iodump/065901_iodump.txt");

QProcess process;
QObject::connect(&process, SIGNAL(error(QProcess::ProcessError)), this, SLOT(myError(QProcess::ProcessError)));
QObject::connect(&process, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QProcess::ProcessState)), this, SLOT(myState(QProcess::ProcessState)));
QObject::connect(&process, SIGNAL(finished(int)), this, SLOT(myEnd(int)));
process.start(app, QStringList() << params);
```

Qprocess is Async, get results with `QObject::connect` (see example)

This will avoid the problem with the "Separators"

Comment: Same answer as @MC ND...See my comments to him.

Comment: Using the process worked - just one additional thing.  You need to add `process.waithForFinished()` or the process will be destroyed before it executes.

Comment: @firelight after running the process sends a "finished" (bat file terminate process), you can then destroy it in your code "main.cpp"

Answer (score 0):

```
system("\"C:\\My Programs\\CPU Analysis\\generateSanity_Scripts\\runIODump.bat\" \"C:\\My Programs\\CPU Analysis\\iodump\\065901_iodump.txt\"");
```

I think you have too many quotes and some wrong slashes

Comment: Is this really the problem +1

Comment: Already tried this...Here is the error: `'C:\My' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`  That's why I have so many quotation marks.